# Angularjs controller is defined but never used

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS. I created a controller in separated file and I called it in my html file and it gave me this error:

> CustomerController is defined but never used!

Here is my HTML code :

```html
<body ng-controller="CustomerController">

  Filter:
  <input type="text" ng-model="customerFilter.name" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th ng-click="doSort('name')"> Name</th>
      <th ng-click="doSort('city')"> City</th>
      <th ng-click="doSort('order')"> Order</th>
      <th ng-click="doSort('joined')"> Joined</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="cust in cutomers | filter : customerFilter | orderBy: sortBy ">
      <td>{{ cust.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ cust.city }}</td>
      <td>{{ cust.order }}</td>
      <td>{{ cust.njoined }}</td>
    </tr>

  </table>
  <br />
  <span>Total custumer : {{ Customers.legth }}</span>
  <script src="angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app/controllers/customersController.js"></script>

</body>
```

and here is my controller file:

```js
function CustomerController($scope) {

  $scope.sortBy = 'name';
  $scope.customers = [{
    joined: '2000-12-02',
    name: 'john',
    city: 'NY',
    order: '9.9956'
  }, {
    joined: '1999-11-10',
    name: 'hf',
    city: 'fjkog',
    order: '8.56'
  }, {
    joined: '1998-4-6',
    name: 'Ali',
    city: 'NYCity',
    order: '7.7956'
  }];
  $scope.doSort = function(propName) {
    $scope.sortBy = propName;
  };
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: add `ng-app="myApp"` and register your controller: `angular.module('myApp', []).controller('CustomerController', CustomerController)`. I think your `angular.js` script should be below `customersController.js`, so it can find a reference to your controller

Comment: @AlekseySolovey I added ng-app in my html tag. can you be more clear plz?

Comment: here is what it should look like: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/28pvXtyNllg9NDSlFj2X?p=preview). _I also removed some typos, so that your code works_

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the controller to your angular module

```
var CustomerController = function($scope) {

  $scope.sortBy = 'name';
  $scope.customers = [{
    joined: '2000-12-02',
    name: 'john',
    city: 'NY',
    order: '9.9956'
  }, {
    joined: '1999-11-10',
    name: 'hf',
    city: 'fjkog',
    order: '8.56'
  }, {
    joined: '1998-4-6',
    name: 'Ali',
    city: 'NYCity',
    order: '7.7956'
  }];
  $scope.doSort = function(propName) {
    $scope.sortBy = propName;
  };
};
angular.module('myApp').controller('CustomerController', CustomerController);
```

then, don't forget to add the NgApp directive in the view

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="CustomerController">

  Filter:
  <input type="text" ng-model="customerFilter.name" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th ng-click="doSort('name')"> Name</th>
      <th ng-click="doSort('city')"> City</th>
      <th ng-click="doSort('order')"> Order</th>
      <th ng-click="doSort('joined')"> Joined</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="cust in cutomers | filter : customerFilter | orderBy: sortBy ">
      <td>{{ cust.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ cust.city }}</td>
      <td>{{ cust.order }}</td>
      <td>{{ cust.njoined }}</td>
    </tr>

  </table>
  <br />
  <span>Total custumer : {{ Customers.legth }}</span>
  <script src="angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app/controllers/customersController.js"></script>

</body>
```